# Increase Cakephp 1.3 form security token expiration time

Tags: cakephp

I'm deep into developing an application in Cakephp 1.3 so while I'd like to upgrade to version 2 I'd rather leave that as a last resort.

My problem is that the Token expiration time for forms when the security component is used is too low. I expect people to sit on this form for a little while, but after 10 minutes using it will result in a blackhole.

Is there anyway to increase the time before the token expires? Cakephp 2 has this option as detailed here: [cakephp 2 security csrf-configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#csrf-configuration)

It doesn't seem to work in 1.3, is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is perfectly do-able, look for the `Session.timeout` number in your `config/core.php` and increase it. The number assigned is the base amount of seconds, the actual amount of time the timeout is set to is depending on your security level also:

- High: `Session.timeout` * 10
- Medium: `Session.timeout` * 100
- Low: `Session.timeout` * 300.

As you want the features of high security, I would keep it on high but increase `Session.timeout` to your needs.

[Further reading](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/924/The-Configuration-Class#CakePHP-Core-Configuration-Variables-931).

**Update**

It actually turns out that the Form token timeout only depends on the security level, and for some reason doesn't take the timeout into effect ([see here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/security.php#L52)), so the only way to increase this is to lower the security level or alter Cake :/

Comment: I don't think this has any effect on the time before a Form token blackholes. Just the actual session time.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I'll have to edit the core file. Another reason to update to version 2.

Comment: Same thing seems to happen: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.1/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php#L36 Possibly intentional but definitely not very flexible

Comment: If you refer to the link I gave in the first post, you can increase the amount of time in Cake 2 in the configuration: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#using-csrf-protection